# java check if date is first Sunday of the Month

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have been looking and searching a lot for this question. I'm really stupid when it comes to using the JAVA Calendar class.

Could anybody please help me to show a simple way of how to get the current time (on the android phone) and check whether is the first Sunday of the month or not.

// Comments in the code examples are very welcome :-)

Comment: It's java so you could just get the current time my doing `System.currentTimeMillis()` initialize a date or calendar with that. Or just do `new java.util.Date()` or even `Calendar.getInstance()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
if (Calendar.SUNDAY == cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <= 7)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had an idea of using <= 7, but was unclear about how to get the day name.

Answer (score 7):

I thought about adding some explanation but this code is pretty self explanatory...

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
int weekDay = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int monthDay = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
if ( (weekDay == Calendar.SUNDAY) && (monthDay <8)) {
   // first sunday of this month
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH` instead of `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`

Comment: @Ali - I was not aware of that. Thank you!

Comment: @Ali - which is not a solution since the first day of the week depends on your locale, which means that you could have the first sunday of the month in the second week.

Comment: @njzk2 Was not aware of the locale issue, thanks, I was personally in favor of the < 8 approach as well.

Comment: @njzk2 + Ali - Thank you very much for our time and the discussion. Was a big help since my country use a different week system (weeks start on Monday).

Answer (score 6):

Simply check if the date is a Sunday and if the date is less than 8...
I'm sure there are better ways, but this would be the simplest.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setDate(myDate);
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if(dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY && dayOfMonth < 8){

}
```

Also there is a `cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)` which you could use for comparison instead of of checking if `dayOfMonth < 8` just do `weekOfMonth == 0` could be 1 instead of 0.

Comment: I'd be careful with `WEEK_OF_MONTH`, as it looks to be influenced by `WEEK_OF_YEAR`rules, which may cause it to produce unexpected results.  That is, if there aren't enough days in the week (since the start of the month) for a complete week, it's actually part of the *previous* month (well, supposing that the start of the week is not sunday).  Since this is region dependant, I'd stick with the day-of-the-month version.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current time use this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

To see if today is the first Sunday in a Month use

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (day == Calendary.Sunday) // today is a Sunday
{
    int day_num = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (day_num <= 7) // the day number is within the 1st 7 days of the month
    {
         // this is the 1st sunday in the month
    }
}
```