# C/C++ - Check if today is first Monday of the Month

Tags: c++, c, date, calendar

How can I check if today is the first Monday of the month using C/C++ code?

It is simpler to get with Java and C# (as shown in links below).

Can anybody help me achieve this using C/C++.

[c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-today-is-the-first-monday-of-the-month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170822/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-today-is-the-first-monday-of-the-month)

[java check if date is first Sunday of the Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999000/java-check-if-date-is-first-sunday-of-the-month)

Comment: It is not. It's Wednesday.

Comment: Take a look at the date_time library in Boost: www.boost.org

Comment: you can get the number in the month and the day in the week and if (number - 7 < 1 and day of week == monday) then it's the first monday of the month

Comment: @DanielDaranas hahahaha that's super-hilarious of you on this serious platform .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(){
   std::time_t result = std::time(NULL);
   const std::tm* t =  std::localtime(&result);
   if(t->tm_wday == 1 and t->tm_mday <= 7)
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    else
    std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
}
```

the code has been tested [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0859467631b573e0a17136e411f3eef5-105ac1d5bf768d76df90c5569141bd7f).

Answer (score 2):

Use boost.date_time [gregorian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class). There is a function `day_clock::local_day()` that gives you todays date. Then you can use the `day()` member function to query the day of the month and the `day_of_week()` member to see if it's Monday. The rest is as in the C# sample you link to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [time()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/time) and [localtime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) to retrie a `struct time *` (let's name it `tp`). Then today is the first Monday in the month if and only if `tp->tm_mday <= 7` (it starts with 1) and `tp->tm_wday == 1` (0 = sunday etc.)